# Why I am not getting the output?

Tags: python, kivy

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class AnchorLayoutDemo(AnchorLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        """

        :rtype: object
        """
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.layout = AnchorLayout(
            anchor_x="left", anchor_y="top"
        )
        self.Button_1 = Button(
            text="Button-1",
            size_hint=(.2, .2),
            background_color=(0, 25.85, 25, 1),
            color=(25.85, 0, 25.45, 1),
            border=(25, 25, 25, 25)
        )
        self.layout.add_widget(self.Button)

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return AnchorLayoutDemo()


MyApp = MyApp()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp.run()
```

Comment: What is this supposed to do? What _do_ you get? What do you expect? Please take the [tour] and read [ask] and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953). Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `__init__()` method of `AnchorLayoutDemo` creates an `AnchorLayout` and adds a `Button` to that `AnchorLayout`, but then does nothing with that `AnchorLayout`. You just need to add another line to the `__init__()` method to add the new `AnchorLayout` to your `AnchorLayoutDemo`:

```
class AnchorLayoutDemo(AnchorLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        """

        :rtype: object
        """
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.layout = AnchorLayout(
            anchor_x="left", anchor_y="top"
        )
        self.Button_1 = Button(
            text="Button-1",
            size_hint=(.2, .2),
            background_color=(0, 25.85, 25, 1),
            color=(25.85, 0, 25.45, 1),
            border=(25, 25, 25, 25)
        )
        self.layout.add_widget(self.Button_1)
        self.add_widget(self.layout)
```

Also needed to change `self.layout.add_widget(self.Button)` to `self.layout.add_widget(self.Button_1)`.

Note that you are putting an `AnchorLayout` inside another `AnchorLayout` (the `AnchorLayoutDemo` is itself an `AnchorLayout`).